# Samsung Smart TV. Switching between scenes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sdk, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying create Samsung SmartTV app. I can't understand how work with scenes. I need create start screen with two buttons, screen for registration with IME, which follows after clicking on one of the buttons and after that screen with categories list.
I can't find clear examples.
I did each scene separately, but how can i unite it all?
Help please

Answer (score 0):

Samsung application for Smart TV is just a single HTML page. Your scenes are just containers within this page so it depends on you how you want to switch between them. You can hide one by getting this container, calling hide method and calling show method on container of scene to show. You can also show new scene over previous or make other type of movement to make new one in front. Most important is to ensure that user has highlighted focused element on page and focused element is on current scene.